# reload markers in leaflet as user pans around

Tags: viewport, leaflet, markers

I am trying to follow the example from this website: http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/getting-started-with-leaflet/ but I can't figure out how to load a list of JSON markers and show them on the map.  Please help.

I can see in the askForPlots() function, it is calling a findbybbox.cgi file to load an array of markers.  I don't have the access to this findbybbox.cgi file but I created one and add the followings in my findbybbox.cgi file

```
[{"name":"Tunbridge Wells, Langton Road, Burnt Cottage",
  "lon":"0.213102",
  "lat":"51.1429",
  "details":"A Grade II listed five bedroom wing in need of renovation."}]
```

But the map won't show the marker.  Any idea what I did wrong?  Here is my leafletembed.js file:

```
    var map;
var ajaxRequest;
var plotlist;
var plotlayers=[];

function initmap(){
    // set up the AJAX stuff
    ajaxRequest=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (ajaxRequest==null) {
        alert ("This browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }

    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('map');

    var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib='Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 12, attribution: osmAttrib});       

    map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.3, 0.7),9);
    map.addLayer(osm);
    askForPlots();
    map.on('moveend', onMapMove);
}

function askForPlots() {
    // request the marker info with AJAX for the current bounds
    var bounds=map.getBounds();
    var minll=bounds.getSouthWest();
    var maxll=bounds.getNorthEast();
    var msg='leaflet/findbybbox.cgi?format=leaflet&bbox='+minll.lng+','+minll.lat+','+maxll.lng+','+maxll.lat;
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = stateChanged; 
    ajaxRequest.open('GET', msg, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

function onMapMove(e) { askForPlots(); }

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { return new XMLHttpRequest(); }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)  { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    return null;
}

function stateChanged() {
    // if AJAX returned a list of markers, add them to the map
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4) {
        //use the info here that was returned
        if (ajaxRequest.status==200) {
            var resp=ajaxRequest.responseText.replace(/[^\u000A\u0020-\u007E]/g, "")
            plotlist=eval("("+resp+")");
            removeMarkers();
            for (i=0;i<plotlist.length;i++) {
                var plotll = new L.LatLng(plotlist[i].lat,plotlist[i].lon, true);
                var plotmark = new L.Marker(plotll);
                plotmark.data=plotlist[i];
                map.addLayer(plotmark);
                plotmark.bindPopup("<h3>"+plotlist[i].name+"</h3>"+plotlist[i].details);
                plotlayers.push(plotmark);
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeMarkers() {
    for (i=0;i<plotlayers.length;i++) {
        map.removeLayer(plotlayers[i]);
    }
    plotlayers=[];
}
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: This would need a better, complete example - ideally something that's online - in order to be debugged. There are too many places where things could be going wrong outside of this posted code, like in the server's response.

Answer (score 0):

```
var msg='leaflet/findbybbox.cgi?format=leaflet&bbox='+minll.lng+','+minll.lat+','+maxll.lng+','+maxll.lat;
```

this is wrong - if you read the tutorial it returns a json object. Replace it with this:

```
var msg='leaflet/test.json';
```

then make a json file called, test.json and throw this in .

```
[
 {
  "name":"Tunbridge Wells, Langton Road, Burnt Cottage",
  "lon":"0.213102",
  "lat":"51.1429",
  "details":"A Grade II listed five bedroom wing in need of renovation."
 }
]
```